# Save full sized figure, not how it's displayed

Tags: matlab

Code + results below. How do I make it so that `test.png` captures the full figure?

Also tried [export_fig](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig), same issue.

I figure there's commands to control the size of the figure window, but I wouldn't know how to make it match the figure size, nor whether it's the best way. Surely it's a solved problem?

---

```matlab
fig = figure;
figobj = tiledlayout(fig, 11, 6, 'Units', 'inches','OuterPosition', [0 0 4 8]);
for i=1:prod(figobj.GridSize)
    nexttile
end
drawnow
exportgraphics(fig, 'test.png')
```

[image]

Comment: In your `tiledlayout` you are setting the size of the figure. I may be understading wrong, but what I read is that you set a size for the figure yourself manually, overwritting MATLAB, and then are having the issue that this size you set is the one being set? I suspect this is not it, can you clarify?

Comment: Well, I use `OuterPosition` as `matplotlib`'s equivalent of `figsize`, just to set the actual size of the figure, not of the figure window. Is that wrong? I tried without it, and now the figure proportions are wrong, and the size is too small.

Comment: I see. Set the size of the figure window as you want, in the `figure` call, it takes optional arguments for that. That may solve your issue.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the problem. But note that MATLAB distinguishes `Position` and `PaperPosition`. The first is for the figure on the screen, the second for the figure on paper (ie when rendered for any type of export, way back when you could only export  by printing on paper). `OuterPosition` was defined later, and I think is meant to be read, not set.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62566744/saving-subplots-with-specific-dimension-matlab

Comment: @Wolfie I've seen this, on another thread it was recommended to use `OuterPosition` over `Position`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the universal approach is, or whether there is one (seemingly contradictory instructions from sources), but what worked here:

```matlab
fig.Position(3:4) = [width height];
```

(and for question's specific `width height`, used `fig = figure('Units', 'inches')`).